# Search multiple files in folder and sub folders python

Tags: python

Trying to search for a search word inside multiple files in current folder and sub folders and print them to a file.

i can print out the files in terminal using os.walk. But i want to search all the files in the folders for a specific word

```
    import glob, os
    
   output_file = 'Funkar.txt'
search_str = '"Prefix"'

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("."):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".wpp"):
             print(os.path.join(root, file))

        with  open(os.path.join(root, file), 'r') as fr, open (output_file,'a',  encoding='utf-8') as fw:
            for i,line in enumerate(fr):
                if line.find(search_str) != -1: 
                    fw.write(line)
```

now gives me

```
in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 12: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: And? What is your question? Do you have a problem with this code? (apart from the bad indentation which is probably a typo?)

Comment: Every time you call `open (output_file,'w'...)` it will overwrite anything already in the file. You most likely want to open for appending `open (output_file,'a'...)`

Comment: ...Or open for writing ***before*** the loop. You probably also need to do `open(os.path.join(root, file), 'r')` to properly open each file. `file` is just the name, relative to your cwd

Comment: Cant figure out the bad indentation, i tried to change the thing u said but cant get it to work, care to show me how? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search and print:

```
import os
def search( folder, word ):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(folder):
        path = root.split(os.sep)
        for filename in files:
            fullname = os.path.join(root, filename)
            if open( fullname ).read().find( word ) != -1:
                print( fullname ) 

search( "FolderName", 'any text')
```

Search and backup searched lines:

```
import os
def search( folder, word, bfile ):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(folder):
        path = root.split(os.sep)
        for filename in files:
            fullname = os.path.join(root, filename)
            if open( fullname ).read().find( word ) != -1:
                print( fullname ) 
                blines = [x for x in open(fullname).readlines() if x.find(word) != -1]
                open( bfile, 'a' ).writelines(blines) 

search( "FolderName", 'any text', 'backup-lines.file')
```

Comment: I think it's not a problem to add two lines, but I'll add it myself

Comment: Why do you insist of `open`ing the files and read them in one lines? That's not very idiomatic... Just open and read them in a normal loop...

Comment: I am not a programmer just trying to learn, thats what i have u guys for :) Well tried to use ur script but cant  manage to get a out file. I dont get any error but i dont get any errors either. I dont wanna specify the folder name i just want to search all sub folders in the folder the scripts is currently in.

Comment: Also i only want to search the files with .wpp file ending, its alot of text in the folders but i dont want it to add those